# chrome.identity.onSignInChanged callback does not fire

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have this hook registered:

```
  chrome.identity.onSignInChanged.addListener(function (identity) {
      console.log('identity changed:', identity);
  });
```

the problem is that this callback never fires. I allow the user to sign in with different Google accounts using these calls:

here is the login:

```
 runUserLogin() {

    const self = this;

    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function (token) {

      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        return alert(String(chrome.runtime.lastError));
      }

      if (!token) {
        return alert('no token available.');
      }

      localStorage.setItem(self.tokenKey, JSON.stringify({token: token}));

      self.token = token;

      const url = MainDataService.CWS_LICENSE_API_URL + chrome.runtime.id;
      const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open('GET', url);
      req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

      req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
          const license = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
          self.license = license;
          self.updateLogin();
        }

      };

      req.send();
    });
  }
```

here is logout:

```
onClickLogout() {

    const self = this;
    const token = this.mds.token;

    if (!token) {
      return alert('You are not logged in.');
    }

    chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token: token}, function () {

      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        return alert(String(chrome.runtime.lastError));
      }

      self.mds.token = null;

      fetch(`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=${token}`).then(function () {
          self.mds.updateLogout();
          alert('Successfully logged out.');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          alert('Could not log out -> ' + err);
        });

    });

  }
```

I see this discussion:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/t57zT9LIRso

But couldn't make anything of it. **Does anyone know why** the `chrome.identity.onSignInChanged` callback does not fire?

Everytime I login/logout, I do see this window, so it should be working correctly:

[image]

Also, `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo()` gives me the new/different identity everytime I login with a different account, so that also seems to suggest that it's working.